# Do I need to return the promise from the entry point of my application?

Tags: node.js, promise

In express, I have the following code:

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    return controller.doSomthingAsync(req).then(() => {
        res.send({message: "Hello World"});
    })
});
```

However, I can also do

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    controller.doSomthingAsync(req).then(() => { // Return removed
        res.send({message: "Hello World"});
    })
});
```

The above also works, but I was wondering if there is any difference between the 2 approaches, and can the second one cause any problems?

Comment: There is no difference between 

Because tough you mention `return` or not the express Response.send will return the body of type any

In your above case tough you don't use res.send returning the body with value `{message: "Hello World"}`

Comment: @Batman OP is not asking about `return`ing the result from  `send`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the piece of code you provided, there is no difference in using the two versions.

The only benefit of that `return` is that any piece of code you put after that would not be executed. For instance, suppose the following piece of code:

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.foo === 'bar') {
        controller.doSomethingAsync(req).then(() => {
            res.send({message: "Hello World"});
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    }

    controller.doSomethingElseAsync(req).then(() => {
        res.send({message: "Hello Universe"});
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

This would produce an error since both of the async operations would be performed and try to send the response.
Adding a `return` in the `if` block would prevent executing the second async operation and the error.

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.foo === 'bar') {
        return controller.doSomethingAsync(req).then(() => {
            res.send({message: "Hello World"});
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error");
        });
    }

    controller.doSomethingElseAsync(req).then(() => {
        res.send({message: "Hello Universe"});
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("Error");
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** As Bergi pointed out, using `else` would do the job as well and avoid to return something that express can't handle.

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.foo === 'bar') {
        controller.doSomethingAsync(req).then(() => {
            res.send({message: "Hello World"});
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error");
        });
    } else {
        controller.doSomethingElseAsync(req).then(() => {
            res.send({message: "Hello Universe"});
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend an `else` for that case, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to return a promise from your express route, as express does not know what to do with promises (a pity!).

However, every time you call a promise-returning function and do not do further chaining and returning it to your caller, i.e. when you end a promise chain, you are responsible for handling errors from it. So it would be appropriate to do

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    controller.getMessageAsync(req).then(msg => {
        res.status(200).send(msg);
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send("Sorry.");
    });
});
```